# heroku rails console query kicks out if too complex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, activerecord, heroku-postgres

I am trying to run a fairly complex query on our production database which is hosted on heroku. These are generally one-off fact finding queries but I am being kicked out each time I try to run it. Locally, the query runs fine and is fairly quick. It's also worse if I assign the result to a variable.

Any help regarding extending the time before heroku kicks me out or other ways to query the database would be greatly appreciated.

FYI - query I was running

```rb
authors = Author.includes(:books).where(books: {book_release_date: ('01/01/2020'.to_date.beginning_of_day..'30/12/2022'.to_date.end_of_day)})
```

The console closes without error which is deeply unhelpful. I am running this from the Heroku CLI i.e. `heroku run rails console`.

Comment: Chances are your query is taking too long or loading too much data in memory. It would help to know the schema of the two tables, whether you have indexes, how many rows are in the tables in total, and whether you have a ballpark idea of how many `books` records would match your query.

Comment: The relation is a 'has_many :through' and there are indexes between the connected tables. Total Books ~(70k) total authors (~50K). Not huge numbers really

Comment: Can you please update the question with this info? Table schemas and relevant lines in the ActiveRecord models? It would also be helpful to see what SQL is being generated.

Answer (score 2):

Solved this now.

This may not be applicable to everyone as you will need to be using dynos other than the basic and hobby types but you can run a one-off dyno using a different size. As the query I was running was potentially using too much memory (although this seemed unlikely) I needed to use a dyno with more ram. As this is a production build and we are using Standard-2x dynos, I could request this through the CLI with the following command

```bash
heroku run --size=standard-2x rails console
```

More information can be found [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos#one-off-dyno-type)

Answer (score 1):

I think  you  should extract the year in sql for your case. Something like that should be much more efficient:

```
Author.includes(:books).where("extract(year  from books.book_release_date) = ?", 2020)
```

Comment: that or a simple `date_trunc` would do